# How do I have a UIBarButtonItem title with a line break?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

In the iPhone music app the right `UIBarButtonItem` title is "Now Playing" (on two lines). I want to do something similar. How can I make the title two lines?

```
   UIBarButtonItem *nowPlayingButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Now Playing", @"button in navigationbar right") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showNowPalyView)];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you creating your `UIBarButtonItem` in code, or in a Storyboard/Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are using as the title, in general  the new line character does the job.

```
 NSString   *titleStr=@"Now\nPlaying";
```

If you are using `UIButton` or `UIlabel` then you have to set the lines accordingly

In case you are using custom button out there

```
[titleButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  // will set the line break mode

[titleButton setTitle:titleStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is Add `UILabel` to  `UIBarButtonItem`  and use `label.numberOfLines = 0`;